# Trying to solve this puzzle but didn't find the right answer. Here is the code generated

Tags: prolog, clpfd, coin-change

You have coins of values 5, 10, 20, 50, 100
whose weights are respectively 2g, 3g, 10g, 25g, 50g.
Your purse is weak so you cannot exceed the weight of 391g. 
And you can put inside it only 3 coins having the same value.
Can you say what is the maximum value of your purse?

Query ::: `change([(Five,Ten,Twenty,Fifty,Hundred),W,S])`

```
range(I,I,[I]).
range(I,K,[I|L]) :-             
    I < K,      
    I1 is I + 1,    
    range(I1,K,L).

coin(X,L) :-
    range(0,3,L1),
    member(X,L1).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

change([(Five,Ten,Twenty,Fifty,Hundred),W,S]) :- 
    coin(Five,L),
    coin(Ten,L),
    coin(Twenty,L),
    coin(Fifty,L),
    coin(Hundred,L),
    W1 = 50*Hundred + 25*Fifty + 10*Twenty +3*Ten+ 2*Five,
    S1 = 5*Five+ 10*Ten+ 20*Twenty + 50*Fifty + 100*Hundred,
    W1 < 391,
    W is W1,
    S is S1,
    maximum(S1).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
maximum(S1) :-
    S is S1,
    threshold(S),
    not( S1 < S).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

threshold(S1) :-
    M is S1,
    not( M < 451).
```

Comment: I thought this is easy enough to solve in your head. 3 of each coin, total weight 270g, total value 555.

Comment: `W1 = 50*Hundred + 25*Fifty + 10*Twenty +3*Ten+ 2*Five,` will not evaluate the expression. So the following `W1 < 391` will not do what you expect. `=/2` is for *unification*, not expression evaluation. You can include the CLPFD library and use `#=/2`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and simply run the following query:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

?- [Hundred,Fifty,Twenty,Ten,Five] ins 0..3,
   Weight #=< 391,
   Weight #=  50*Hundred + 25*Fifty + 10*Twenty +  3*Ten + 2*Five,
   Value  #= 100*Hundred + 50*Fifty + 20*Twenty + 10*Ten + 5*Five,
   labeling([max(Value)], [Hundred,Fifty,Twenty,Ten,Five]).
Hundred = 3, Fifty = 3, Twenty = 3, Ten = 3, Five = 3, Value = 555, Weight = 270 ;
Hundred = 3, Fifty = 3, Twenty = 3, Ten = 3, Five = 2, Value = 550, Weight = 268 ;
...
```

Comment: @PuneetTiwari. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

'generate and test' performed by library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)):

```
change(S) :-
    aggregate(max(V), P^W^(purse(P, W, V), W < 391), S).

purse(P, W, V) :-
    length(P, 5),
    maplist(between(0, 3), P),
    scalar(P, [2,3,10,25,50], W),
    scalar(P, [5,10,20,50,100], V).

scalar(Vs, Fs, S) :-
    foldl([V,F,V0,U]>>(U is V0+V*F), Vs, Fs, 0, S).
```

scalar/3 is a bit of overengineering, take it as a suggestion to look into [scalar_product](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=scalar_product/4)/4 if you go with library([clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd))